# OBIEE 11g: How do you navigate to another report and pass parameters (using Go URL)?

Tags: http, oracle11g, obiee

I'm trying to recreate the work in this [blog post](http://www.rittmanmead.com/2010/10/oracle-bi-ee-11g-navigation-passing-parameters-using-hierarchical-columns/) using OBIEE 11g.

What is the precise syntax for the Go URL parameters?

Alternatively, is there a way to navigate to another report and pass parameters using OBIEE 11g without jumping through the hoops of this URL method?  This task was much easier to accomplish using 10g.

Answer (score 1):

it is much more simple. Just move to the criteria of the request and click required column by which you want to navigate. In the column properties of the request there is option naming INTERACTION in that option you will find "Add action link"-> BI content and then just select required request or the required dashboard page. it will navigate on it.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

I second the approach recommending the Action Links Framework to navigate to another Analysis in Answers and to pass the payload. This one picture says it all.

[image]

Here are the detailed steps, taken from this [tutorial](http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/fmw/bi/bi1113/actionframework/actionframework.htm).

**Add an Action Link to the Analysis**

1. Click the Criteria tab.
2. Click More Options button  for the D4 Company column and select Column Properties.
3. In the Column Properties dialog box, click the Interaction tab, then click the drop-down list in the Value section to view the available interaction settings. In the Interaction tab, you can specify interactions for column headings and values. The default interaction is to drill in any associated hierarchy. Other options are to send Master-Detail events, which allow user actions in a column in a Master analysis to reflect in child analyses, and to initiate an action using Action links.
4. Select Action Links from the drop-down list. In the Action Links list, you can view, add, edit, and delete actions associated with the column. Notice that you can have multiple action links associated with a column. By default, actions available for a column appear in a popup when a user clicks the column value or heading in an analysis. You can use the "Do not display in a popup if only one action is available at runtime" option to reset this so that in the event only one action is available for a value or heading, the action is executed upon the user interaction. Leave this option unchecked.
5. Click the Add Action Link button.
6. In the New Action Link dialog box, click the Create New Action button  and select Navigate to BI Content. This new action is an inline action, in that it is created as part of the analysis it is saved in. Later, you will build and use named actions, which are saved in the Presentation catalog for reuse.
7. In the Select BI Content for Action dialog box, navigate to Shared Folders/2. Functional Examples/Demo, select the Order Details analysis, and click OK.
8. In the Create New Action dialog box, click OK.
9. In the New Action dialog box, click OK, then click OK to close the Column Properties dialog box..

Answer (score -1):

You don't say if you've gone through the documentation, here: http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E14571_01/bi.1111/e16364/apiwebintegrate.htm#i1005050

Failing that, you could try raising a Service Request (SR) with Oracle and asking the question, at http://supporthtml.oracle.com